# How can I pairwise sum two equal-length tuples

Tags: python, tuples

How can I get the pairwise sum of two equal length tuples? For example if I have (0,-1,7) and (3,4,-7) I would like to have (3,3,0) as answer.

Comment: A duplicate of a question asked a year and a half ago which didn't receive any good answers seems fine.  All of the answers in that are map-based, which is much less clean than a list comprehension/generation expression (below).  The accepted answer in that one is much worse--overriding a class just to perform a method on it makes no sense at all.

Comment: I suppose the reason for the accepted answer in that one is because that's the particular weird behavior the question asked for, so it's not really the answerer's fault.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
tuple(map(lambda (x, y): x + y, zip((0,-1,7), (3,4,-7))))
```

If you prefer to avoid `map` and `lambda` then you can do:

```
tuple(x + y for x,y in zip((0,-1,7), (3,4,-7)))
```

**EDIT**: As one of the answers pointed out, you can use sum instead of explicitly splitting the tuples returned by `zip`. Therefore you can rewrite the above code sample as shown below:

```
tuple(sum(t) for t in zip((0,-1,7), (3,4,-7)))
```

Reference: [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum).

Comment: The list comprehension is usually preferable.  This is far more immediately intuitive than all of the functional answers in #497885.

Comment: @Glenn: agreed. That said somehow I find it easier to first think in terms of map and filter and then map it (no pun intended :P) to a list comprehension.

Comment: I'm the other way around: list comprehensions (in this case, generator expressions, actually) are naturally intuitive to me, but I have to think about map--probably because it's much less frequently used in Python.

Answer (score 6):

Use sum():

```
>>> tuple(sum(pair) for pair in zip((0,-1,7), (3,4,-7)))
```

or

```
>>> tuple(map(sum, zip((0,-1,7), (3,4,-7))))
```

Comment: `tuple(map(operator.add, (0, -1, 7), (3, 4, -7)))`

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D +1, `operator.add` is about 2.2x faster than using `map` and `zip`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> t1 = (0,-1,7)
>>> t2 = (3,4,-7)
>>> tuple(i + j for i, j in zip(t1, t2))
(3, 3, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively (good if you have very big tuples or you plan to do other mathematical operations with them):

```
> import numpy as np
> t1 = (0, -1, 7)
> t2 = (3, 4, -7)
> at1 = np.array(t1)
> at2 = np.array(t2)
> tuple(at1 + at2)
(3, 3, 0)
```

Cons: more data preparation is needed. Could be overkill in most cases.

Pros: operations are very explicit and isolated. Probably very fast with big tuples.